# Variable value does not display when assigned a value

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

Please assist in the below code for java.

**CLASS1**:
I've the following code in Class1:

```
public String getnumber()
    {
          return this.number;
    }
```

**CLASS2**:
I've another class Class2 with code set as:

```
Class1 cla = new Class1();
public String number_to_compute=cla.getnumber() // This is variable
```

**CLASS3**:
I've a third class `class3` where I'm executing some other methods:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
Class2 class2 = new Class2();

 public static void main(String args[])
      {
           System.out.println(class1.getumber()); 
          System.out.println(class2.number_to_compute);
      }
```

**OUTCOME**:

In the above problem, `class1.getumber()` works fine and gives correct answer where as `class2.number_to_compute` outtputs `null`

Why is `class2.number_to_compute` a `null` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Class2` you compute `number_to_compute` using `cla` object which is made inside `Class2`. (It doesn't use `Class1` object in `Class3`)

Set the value of `number` in `cla` of Class2 properly.

```
class Class1
{
  String number;
  public String getnumber()
  {
    return this.number;
  }
}

class Class2
{
  Class1 cla; 
  public String number_to_compute;

  public Class2()
  {
    cla = new Class1();
    cla.number = "1";
    number_to_compute = cla.getnumber();
  }
}

class Class3
{
  Class1 class1;
  Class2 class2;

  public Class3()
  {
    class1 = new Class1();
    class1.number = "2";
    class2 = new Class2();
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Class3 cl = new Class3();
    System.out.println(cl.class2.cla.getnumber()); 
    System.out.println(cl.class2.number_to_compute);
  }
}
```

or you can use the `Class1` object you made in `Class3`

```
 class Class1
{
  String number;
  public String getnumber()
  {
    return this.number;
  }
}

class Class2
{
  Class1 cla; 
  public String number_to_compute;

  public Class2()
  {
    cla = new Class1();
    cla.number = "1";
    number_to_compute = cla.getnumber();
  }
}

class Class3
{
  Class1 class1;
  Class2 class2;

  public Class3()
  {
    class1 = new Class1();
    class1.number = "2";
    class2 = new Class2();
    class2.cla = class1;
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Class3 cl = new Class3();
    System.out.println(cl.class2.cla.getnumber()); 
    System.out.println(cl.class2.number_to_compute);
  }
}
```

By the way, it is always good to [use setters and getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) to set instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, You are creating new object for `class1`  in both `class2` and `class3` separately that's why both object is not dependent to each other.. if you want `class2` and `class3` have the same instance of `class1`, you need to create `class1` as `singleton` which will always give the single object instance of `class1`.

Try as below :-

```
public class Class1
{
    private String number = null;
    private static Class1 class1 = null;
    public static Class1 getInstance() 
    {
         if(class1 == null)
            {
               class1 = new Class1();
            }
         return class1;
      }

    private Class1(){}

    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    Class1 cla = Class1.getInstance();
    public String number_to_compute = cla.getNumber();
}

public class Class3
{
  static Class1 class1 = Class1.getInstance();

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    class1.setNumber("123");
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    System.out.println(class1.getNumber());
    System.out.println(class2.number_to_compute);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: I'm still getting null.

Comment: @Prabhath could you tell me first when you call it's setter??

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me. The only thing I saw that needed to be added was the `static` keyword to the `class1` and `class2` definitions in `Class3`. See below.

```
public class Class1
{
    String number = "1234";

    public String getnumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    Class1 cla = new Class1();
    public String number_to_compute = cla.getnumber();
}

public class Class3
{
    static Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    static Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(class1.getnumber());
        System.out.println(class2.number_to_compute);
    }
}
```

When run, it outputs

```
1234
1234
```